# Manter sessões em subdomínios com o CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, session

Estou tendo problemas em manter as sessões ativas entre os subdomínios do sistema, estou utilizando a versão CakePHP 2.4.7, já adicionei a função abaixo no `App/bootstrap.php`

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', env('HTTP_BASE'));
```

ja coloquei no `App/core.php`

```
Configure::write('Security.level', 'low');
Configure::write('Session.save', 'session_save_handler');
```

Mas mesmo assim não funciona, tem mais alguma configuração para que isso funcione?

Comment: pode colocar o exemplo de subdominio? ele tem qual endereço? endereço a qual pasta?

Comment: aproveita e da uma olhada nesse topico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519570/cakephp-keep-session-from-main-domain-across-to-a-subdomain

Comment: Olá @IgorMartins, eu já tinha visto o link postado e foi com base nele que fiz as configurações, mas até o momento sem sucesso. o link é accounts.meusite.com.br e mesmo que coloque account.meusite.com.br apontando para mesma pasta não funciona, no `ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.meusite.com.br')`, só uma obs.: estou trabalhando local.

Comment: Deu certo tive que alterar algumas configurações no php.ini e seguindo este exemplo na documentação (http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/pt/The-Manual/Core-Components/Sessions.html). fica a dica! Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem uma configuração dentro do arquivo app/Config/core.php para alterar o cookie de sessão do dominio:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php',
    'ini' => array(
        'cookie_domain' => '.example.com'
    )
));
```

Eu fiz o teste e funcionou corretamente.

Comment: Já tinha feito isso antes, agora não sei se é porque estou usando local, mas dá um loop infinito na aplicação.

Comment: Eu testei tanto local quanto na web para garantir e funcionou corretamente. Se tem controle de versão é interessante voltar ao momento que funcionava e tentar fazer um diff para tentar entender o motivo do não funcionamento. Boa sorte

Comment: Há me desculpe, o loop se dá no firefox quando coloco o código acima, mesmo utilizando a ultima versão, já no chrome aparece => Unable to configure the session, setting cookie_domain failed. => Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

Comment: Isso ta mais estranho que correr pelado ... tentou colocar em um server para testes ?

Comment: Rss! Vou fazer isso, estou no momento utilizando o xampp, vou instalar tudo manualmente e fazer o teste em um servidor web. Obrigado! =D

Comment: Outra dica .. eu utilizo o linux para dev e testes ou seja ajuda no debug de erros, caso não tenha esta opção utilize o cygwin para fazer tail nos erros em tempo real, torna muito mais facil o desenvolvimento